# Make Master Page (Screen) on JavaFX

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

I have some trouble when I arrange my javafx layout. I use BorderPane. Top and Left area are for static view (page). I placed MenuBar on the Top, and some Buttons on the Left, like in the picture. And, when I click a Button, the content will be opened in the center. Every Button has different content and layout. "Money Box" button will have TabPane for its content, and I have created it using SceneBuilder. "Cafe" button will have Table for its content, and I have created it using SceneBuilder. What strategy, or what do I have to do for solving my problem here.

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qJ8I.png

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what exactly you are looking for, and based on your description there are many ways to accomplish what you need.  I have a similar behavior that we use different FXMLs for each selected layout and load those and remove those from the scene.

```
private void openMiddleNode(String view) {}
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent node = loader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(view).openStream());
        //If your middle section has it's own controller (likely an instance variable, if it needs to respond to events from the parent controller)
        MyController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.anyCustomSetup();

        //Assumes that this middlePane is defined in the FXML and initialized above
        middlePane.getChildren().setAll(node);
    } catch (IOException ie){
        if(logger.isErrorEnabled()){
            logger.error("An exception has been thrown: " + ie);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thak you for your answer. My problem is how to place give an action on button in the left side of borderpane to show a fxml file design in the CENTER of borderpane. I am using borderpane for root pane.

Comment: Then use borderPane.setCenter(node)  instead of middlePane.getChildren().setAll() assuming borderPane is the name of your pane.  Call this method from your click handler.